Migrating source code from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 11 - Range Check Error
I'm migrating source code for my old application from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 11.
When I run source code in Delphi 11, I receive lots of message boxes saying "Range Check Error".
Is there a way to easily get focus on the line in the source code which is responsible for this error?
I have found the cause of these errors could be with how I work with strings, for example when I commented the line with abcd procedure in the code below then one of these error messages disappeared.
function TForm1.test(input: string; pos: integer): string;
begin
  abcd('Input Char > ' + input[pos]);
...


Are you running in debug mode?

What are the actual values of input and pos when the error occurs? Is pos <= 0 or pos > Length(input)?

Use a tool like madExcept or EurekaLog

If you are running in debug mode and the message box pops up then the chances are that your environment is set to ignore the range check error so you do not get your first chance exception.
To remove this open Tools|Options, and in the dialog go down to Debugger Options|Embarcadero Debuggers|Language Exceptions and in the right hand window uncheck the box ERangeError
